# How can I convert URLs to Markdown syntax, but NOT interfere with URLs already in Markdown syntax?

Tags: php, regex

A system I am writing uses Markdown to modify links, but I also want to make plain links active, so that typing `http://www.google.com` would become an active link. To do this, I am using a regex replacement to find urls, and rewrite them in Markdown syntax.  The problem is that I can not get the regex to not also parse links already in Markdown syntax.

I'm using the following code:

```
$value = preg_replace('@((?!\()https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '[$1]($1)', $value);
```

This works well for plain links, such as `http://www.google.com`, but I need it to ignore links already in the Markdown format.  I thought the section (?!() would prevent it from matching urls which followed a parenthesis, but it would seem that I am in error.

I realize that even this is not an ideal solution (if it worked), but this is pushing beyond my regex abilities.

Comment: I ran across this but needed it for JS (which doesn't have negative assertions) and decided I might as well share what I came up with (I'm no RegEx expert though) in case anyone is in the same boat:
var parsed = text.replace(/(^|[^\]\(])((https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig, "$1[$2]($2)");

Comment: @klamping yours doesn't work for me. `.replace(/(^|[^\[\(:])((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-]+(\.[\w\-]+)+([\w\-.,@?\^=%&:\/~+#\-]*[\w@?\^=%&;\/~+#\-])?)/gi, ' [$2]($2)')` - far from perfect, but it does the job. Although it messes with `[]:link` definitions - there cannot be space between `:` and `link`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `(?<!\()` is what you meant.  If the match position is at the beginning of `http://www.google.com`, it's not the *next* character you need to check, but the *previous* one.  In other words you need a negative *lookbehind*, not a negative *lookahead*.

Answer (score 0):

regexes are notoriously bad at stuff like this, you might end up with all sorts of clever html exploits you never could have thought of.  IMO you should mod the markdown script to flag markdown URLs as it sees them, so you can ignore flagged URLs when you find them all with a very very simple search that doesn't leave complexity to hack.